# Creating search pages for specific content types

Tags: 7, search

I am currently in the process of implementing different search pages, with distinct layouts/templates and behaviors for specific content types (a search for "blog" nodes, one for "video" nodes, etc), and I am confused as to what the best approach is for this. I've read that the Facet API module may help implement this behavior. I'm already using Apache Solr for the searching component, is this the best approach and what's the path of least resistance if using Facet API?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best method for me is [Search API](https://www.drupal.org/project/search_api):

> This module provides a framework for easily creating searches on any entity known to Drupal, using any kind of search engine.

Uses multiple backends (solr, database, elastic search), is fully integrated with views, etc.